# horizontal alignment problem in tabular containing math equation

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm using {unicode-math} to control the size of mathfont.
But in this table a have the problem of horizontal alignment
[image]

and when I put `$y$` at the place of `$f(x)$`, there is no problem of alignment !

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{tabular}{|C{1cm}||*{6}{C{0.8cm}|}}
\hline
$x$   & $-2$ & $-3$ & $1$ & $2$  &      &  \\ 
\hline
$f(x)$ &  &   &  $3$ & $5$ & $9$  & $11$ \\  
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: I think you mean vertical alignment not horiziontal but please provide a small complete document that shows the problem,

Comment: If I make your code snippet minimally compilable by (a) using the `article` document class and (b) loading the `array` and `unicode-math` packages, I am unable to reproduce the issue shown in the screenshot. Spefically, the terms in the second row all line up on the same baseline. Hence, do please provide more information about you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this using the [**`tabularray`**](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{|Q[m,c,1cm,mode=imath]||*{6}{Q[m,c,0.8cm,mode=imath]|}}
\toprule
x   & -2 & -3 & 1 & 2  &      &  \\ 
\midrule
f(x) &  &   &  3 & 5 & 9  & 11 \\  
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

`\usepackage{booktabs}`: This line imports the [**`booktabs`**](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package, which provides commands to create high-quality tables with improved horizontal lines.
`\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}`: This line imports the **`booktabs`** library from **`tabularray`**, allowing you to use booktabs commands within tabularray environments.

`Q[m,c,1cm,mode=imath]` means the cells are vertically centered (`m`), horizontally centered (`c`), and have a width of 1cm and. Additionally, as suggested by [**@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz), `mode=imath` allows you to avoid repeating $...$ in every cell.

Comment: You could set `mode=imath` for all cells, then you don't have to repeat `$...$` in every cell.

Comment: Thank you, Sam, for the suggestion. I've updated the response accordingly.

Comment: Nice! Much cleaner code!

Answer (score 1):

The standard `array` package provides fixed width columns that don't require `\arraybackslash` tricks. The column type is `w`:

- `w{c}{<width>}` for a centered column with specified width
- `w{l}{<width>}` for a left aligned column with specified width
- `w{r}{<width>}` for a right aligned column with specified width

In your case the table will probably be a math display and you can use `array` instead of `tabular`, sparing on `$` symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{|w{c}{1cm}||*{6}{w{c}{0.8cm}|}}
\hline
x   & -2 & -3 & 1 & 2  &      &  \\ 
\hline
f(x) &  &   &  3 & 5 & 9  & 11 \\  
\hline
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With less rules:

```
\begin{array}{w{c}{1cm}|*{6}{w{c}{0.8cm}}}
x   & -2 & -3 & 1 & 2  &      &  \\
\hline
f(x) &  &   &  3 & 5 & 9  & 11 \\
\end{array}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, it's perfect